# Trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server on Pycharm

Tags: sql-server, pycharm, pymssql

I can't connect to the SQL Server, I have tried everything, chatgpt, Google and now I need your help

This is what I have have:

- SQL Server is using Windows authentication and hostname/instant name (that shows up in SSMS as `[PC-NAME]\SQLEXPRESS`)
- Host is `localhost` (I believe)
- Tcp/ip is on for the server, I tried port 1433 and telnet to resolve the issue but no hope

I get this error

> The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed.
>
> Error: "Connection refused: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."

**PS: I am fairly new so I don't know any techy term and just got started using Pycharm**

**EDIT: ChatGPT said to check my firewall for an inbound rule names 'SQL server Browser or related' But i did not find any rule related to SQL at all**

Comment: 1434 is not the port you are looking for - that is the Dedicated Administrator Connection and only allows a single connection from a member of the sysadmin role.

Comment: The TCP/IP protocol is typically not enabled by default on SQL Server Express editions. Did you enable it yourself via SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager? Did you restart the SQL Server service after enabling the TCP/IP protocol so that the changes can take effect? After restarting the service you should be able to connect on its enabled ports (1433 if you enabled those).

Comment: You shouldn't combine instance name and port, it's either or. I prefer to skip instance name and use port directly, but it doesn't look like you have the correct port. Did you check the ports in the Sql server Manager?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Enabled TCP/IP protocol myself and restarted server but no luck, also idk if port 1433 is enabled or not.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Port 1434 is typo my bad, Ill edit the post and fix it

Comment: @siggemannen how to check ports?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your SQL Server browser is on and running, if not here's the procedure to do so

```
 - Open your Server Configuration Manager and Click SQL Server Service 
 - Find 'SQL server Browser'
 - Right-Click and click on 'Properties' then go to
   Service
 - Click 'Start mode' and set it to either   
   Automatic/Manual(depending on your needs)
 - Click Apply and OK.
 - Restart the server(recommended).
```

There you go! SQL Server Browser is now Enabled!

If this doesnt work either your port might be block for which you need to add a new Inbound rule in your Firewall settings.
Here's a link for it Click [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiRy7H61L6BAxVl3TgGHe0IClcQFnoECBEQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Foptics.ansys.com%2Fhc%2Fen-us%2Farticles%2F7144748040467-Adding-inbound-rules-to-Windows-defender-firewall&usg=AOvVaw0FzP0FSxMt6WhNV4h4S5n1&opi=89978449)